# Azure fails when try to create a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, rest, azure

When I try to create a MySQL database on Microsoft Azure using pure REST request (`PUT`) to:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionid>/resourceGroups
/resource-<id>/providers/successbricks.cleardb/databases/<my-database>?
api-version=2014-04-01
```

I am getting this error:

`HTTP STATUS CODE 400 Bad Request`

> Error message: 'Legal terms have not been accepted for this item on
>   this subscription. To accept legal terms, please go to the Azure
>   portal (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=534873) and configure
>   programmatic deployment for the Marketplace item or create it there
>   for the first time'

So I went to Microsoft Azure Portal, and I accepted the legal terms. I tried again, same error. I searched in almost the entire Azure Portal for some configuration about this and I found nothing.

Someone have the same problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try by creating a dummy item from marketplace using Portal and then try again using REST API?

Comment: Yes, I created successfully an instance of MySQL from Marketplace. Everything normal when using Azure Portal and Marketplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys, found the solution. I don't know why, but if we change the JSON attribute `{ "plan.name": "Pay-As-You-Go" }` to `{ "plan.name": "Free" }` the database is created successfully.

I opened a support ticket to know which are the MySQL available plans. I will update the answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

you should not only accept the terms but follow the procedure of making the programmatic access possible. It should be on the license page.

[image]

Comment: I have searched for this link and there is nothing in my screen. I have taken a screenshot. Please, take a look. http://i.imgur.com/E6NCZxy.png

Answer (score 0):

Programmatic deployment only can be found in Virtual Machines MySQL, not in Data Storage MySQL Database. Try REST request after you enabled programmatic Deployment.

[image]

In addition, I successfully created a MySQL database using REST API without reproducing your question, but note that the request body need to be sent as well when using PUT request.

Comment: Did you use Bitnami solution or ClearDB? I am trying to deploy a ClearDB solution.